# Binding parameters as array postgres java

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to bind a prepared statement parameter which is a array  PostgreSQL. Here's an  example Query:

```
prepareStatement("UPDATE " + emailsFromDb.get(i) +  " SET columne =testvalue '," + id + "' WHERE id IN (?)" );
```

I read from txt file value as array this is code read from txt

```
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while(inFile1.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(inFile1.nextLine());
}
String[] testArray = sb.toString().split(", ");
```

and prepare the array in sql

```
Array bulkarr=  connector.createArrayOf("INT", testArray);
pr.setArray(1, bulkarr);

pr.executeUpdate();
```

and the result I have this error

```
2017-11-02 17:12:58 --ERROR-ApplicationErrorMessage : 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 106
```

I need to update with where in array postgres

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` operator does not support arrays, you need to use `ANY`

```
WHERE id = ANY (?)
```

then you can pass an array, through `setArray()`

---

Unrelated, but: If you are using a `PreparedStament` you should pass **all** values through that. Concatenating input into a SQL string is a **really**, really bad idea.

Comment: what can I do I need to update bukl from txt whta tis the best way ??